# Реализовать функции отмены / подтверждения react

Tags: reactjs

По заданию нужно:
"В state компонента есть поле invited и сurrentUser. Среди invited находится пользователь, который авторизован в системе, и его id соответствует currentUser. Применять изменения нужно к этому пользователю.
Допишите три функции: getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus, confirm и cancel.
Функция confirm должна изменять состояние status у текущего пользователя на "confirmed", а cancel — на "canceled". Функция getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus должна возвращать статус текущего пользователя. Использовать эту функцию необходимо в методах confirm и cancel."

Все 3 функции были пустыми, всё что в них есть это мои шаги.
По идее при нажатии одной из двух кнопок происходит вызов функции confirm или cancel. Там создаю переменную принимающую результат от функции getCurrent... Она должна по id найти пользователя и вернуть его мне в переменную. После этого я в функции погружаюсь в стейт и меняю значение.

Но что-то у меня не работает, я не могу понять что я делал не так. Буду благодарен за помощь и объяснения.

```js
const STATUS_CONFIRMED = 'confirmed';
const STATUS_PENDING = 'pending';
const STATUS_CANCELED = 'canceled';

const renderStatus = {
  confirmed: 'Подтверждён',
  pending: 'Не подтверждён',
  canceled: 'Отменён'
};

class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="user">
        <img className="user__avatar" src={this.props.avatar} alt="фото." />
        <div className="user__info">
          <p className="user__text">{`${this.props.name}, ${this.props.role}`}</p>
          {this.props.status && (
            <p className={`user__status ${this.props.status}`}>{renderStatus[this.props.status]}</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class CalendarEvent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentUser: 34047044,
    owner: { id: 34049221, name: 'Павел', role: 'Технический директор', avatar: './images/1.png' },
    subject: 'Обсуждение редизайна административной панели сайта',
    invited: [
      {
        id: 34049119,
        name: 'Татьяна',
        role: 'Дизайнер',
        status: STATUS_CONFIRMED,
        avatar: './images/2.png'
      },
      {
        id: 34047044,
        name: 'Кирилл',
        role: 'Разработчик',
        status: STATUS_PENDING,
        avatar: './images/3.png'
      },
      {
        id: 34048196,
        name: 'Константин',
        role: 'Менеджер',
        status: STATUS_CANCELED,
        avatar: './images/4.png'
      }
    ],
    durationdate: '10.11.2021',
    timeStart: '14:30',
    duration: 40,
    location: 'Переговорная №4'
  };

  getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus() {
    for(let i=0; i < this.state.invited.length; i++){
      if(this.state.currentUser === this.state.invited[i].id){
        return this.state.invited[i].status
      }
    }    
  }

  confirm() {  
    const getStatus = this.getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus()
    this.setState(prevState)({
      ...prevState,
      invited: [
        ...prevState.invited,           
        {getStatus}: "confirmed"
      ]
    })
  }

  cancel() {
    const getStatus = this.getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus()
    this.setState(prevState({
      ...prevState,
      invited: [
        ...prevState.invited,           
        {getStatus}: "canceled"
      ]
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const confirmed = this.getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus() === STATUS_CONFIRMED;
    return (
      <section className="main">
        <div className="calendar">
          <p className="calendar__menu">Тема:</p>
          <h1 className="calendar__title">{this.state.subject}</h1>
          <p className="calendar__menu">Организатор:</p>
          <User {...this.state.owner} />
          <p className="calendar__menu">Приглашены:</p>
          <div className="calendar__invited">
            {this.state.invited.map((user, index) => (
              <User key={index} {...user} />
            ))}
          </div>
          <p className="calendar__menu">Дата:</p>
          <p className="calendar__text">{this.state.durationdate}</p>
          <p className="calendar__menu">Начало:</p>
          <p className="calendar__text">{this.state.timeStart}</p>
          <p className="calendar__menu">Продолжительность:</p>
          <p className="calendar__text">{this.state.duration}</p>
          <p className="calendar__menu">Место:</p>
          <p className="calendar__text">{this.state.location}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="button cancel" type="button" onClick={this.cancel}>
            Отменить
          </button>
          <button className="button confirm" type="button" onClick={this.confirm}>
            Подтвердить
          </button>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CalendarEvent />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 160px 1fr;
  gap: 24px 20px;
}

.calendar__menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0;
}

.calendar__title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.calendar__invited {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.user:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.user__avatar {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.user__info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.user__text {
  margin: 0;
}

.user__status {
  margin: 4px 0 0;
}

.user__status.confirmed {
  color: #02B241;
}
.user__status.pending {
  color: #999999;
}
.user__status.canceled {
  color: #FF3B30;
}

.calendar__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.buttons {
  margin: auto 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cancel {
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.confirm {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .main {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/fonts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/react/libs/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/react/libs/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/react/libs/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  <script type='text/jsx' src="task.jsx"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

функция getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus возвращает тебе строку вида "STATUS_CONFIRMED" потом ты меняешь стэйт у юзера в поле с таким же именем, у объекта пользователя нет свойства с таким именем, там только status
setState у тебя тоже не правильный

```
this.setState(prevState =>{
    const {invited, currentUser} = prevState 
    const changedInvited = invited.map(item =>{
        if(item.id ===currentUser){
            return {...item, status: "confirmed"}
        }
            return item 
        })
          return {...prevState, invited: changedInvited }
        })
```

тогда не понятно зачем вообще нужна функция getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus

Comment: Как ты советуешь это поправить в рамках задания? 
Что getCurrentUserConfirmationStatus возвращает статус текущего пользователя.
А confirm и cancel используют эту функцию для изменения state статуса пользователя.

Comment: @Dmitriy я исправил ответ, setState тоже ты не правильно делал, установи react dev tools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=ru что бы просматривать состояние в панели разработчика